# column width for pageBlockSection

Tags: visualforce, css, pageblocksection

So I am using a pageBlockSection with two columns to display some details for particular SObjects. The first column would hold a label and the second column would hold the value for that particular label. Here is a picture to illustrate this:
[image]

So I am aligning the items in column 1 to the right and the items in column 2 to the left so that they look close to each other but have the same spacing between them. However as you can see there is a large amount of whitespace to the left of the labels (created date, start date, etc) and some of the values have to wrap around due to their length. So I would like to shorten the width of the first column and extend the length of the second. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I ran into this challenge and was able to solve it with width percentages. Check out my example below.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width:10%" labelStyle="width:23%" >
<apex:outputLabel >Field 2</apex:outputLabel>
<apex:inputField value="{!obj__c.field2}" style="width:80px"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: this is kind of clever but does it work at the `pageBlockSection` level which was the question posed?

Comment: While it wasn't the level that the question asked, it still worked perfectly. It actually helped because when I only had pageBlockSection I would have to set render attributes for both the label and the data so there was repeated render attributes. Now I have a rendered for the pageBlockSectionItem which helps readability. Thanks for showing a new way to approach the problem

Comment: In fact, you only need to apply the dataStyle and labelStyle to the first pageBlockSectionItem to get all the rows to be x% and y%. The other pageBlockSection elements don't even need to use pageBlockSectionItem as everything ends up rendered in an html table

Comment: Brilliant thank you!